# Replacing a button with another using replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Now I have two buttons that enables me to follow or unfollow a user by looking at my follower list. For example when someone is already in my followers, unfollow button appears, in other case, follow button appears.

```
followProfile: function (e) {
    var personalData = $('#personal-information').serializeObject();
    var postParams = {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $.cookie('csrftoken'),
        personal_data: JSON.stringify(personalData)
    };

    $.post('/follow/', postParams, function(resp) {
        $(".follow-button").replaceWith( $(".unfollow-button").show() );
    })
},
unfollowProfile: function (e) {
    var personalData = $('#personal-information').serializeObject();
    var postParams = {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $.cookie('csrftoken'),
        personal_data: JSON.stringify(personalData)
    };

    $.post('/unfollow/', postParams, function(resp) {
        $(".unfollow-button").replaceWith( $(".follow-button").show() );
    })
},
```

Here it is my problem; when I click to follow someone, the button changes and it becomes unfollow. However when I click unfollow again, the button now disappears. I am new in Javascript and Backbone.js so I haven't ever used this method before. Can you tell me why the button disappears? What is wrong here?

Clarification: When I call, "unfollow", it replaces unfollow to follow correctly (Now it is follow). But when I click follow now, instead of writing "unfollow" button disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the method `.show()` which does not return a `JQueryObject`, which the `.replaceWith()` function expects.

```
$.post('/unfollow/', postParams, function(resp) {
    var followButton = $(".follow-button");
    $(".unfollow-button").replaceWith( followButton );
    followButton.show();
})
```

Comment: Oh I see your point that's right but when I write .show();, it still disappears :/ I am editing the question. Thank you for your reply and correction.

Comment: It gives the same result. First it changes follow to unfollow button correctly but again I cannot change unfollow to follow back. I think replaceWith() function overwrites. I mean when makes "follow" to "unfollow', there is no way to change "unfollow" to "follow" again.

Comment: Instead of using `.replaceWith()` try out `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using simply;

```
$.post('/unfollow/', postParams, function(resp) {
    document.getElementById('twitter-follow-button').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('twitter-unfollow-button').style.display = 'none';

})
$.post('/follow/', postParams, function(resp) {
    document.getElementById('twitter-follow-button').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('twitter-unfollow-button').style.display = 'inline';

})
```

I need to preserve the buttons so I think this is the simpler and better solution for me. replaceWith(), as far as I understand, does not preserve the button.

Many thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById('twitter-follow-button')` ... well ideally `id` will be unique in the document, but using global selectors like this in a backbone project is a bad practice.